# Ошибка Use of undefined constant

Tags: php, wordpress

Появилась ошибка на сайте Notice: Use of undefined constant **FILEIT** - assumed '**FILEIT**' in /sites/princeska.com.ua/index.php on line 17. 
Содержимое строки 17 - require( dirname( **FILEIT** ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
Если добавляю кавычки '**FILEIT** ' - ошибка пропадает, просто белый экран. 
Перепробовал уже все варианты - ничего не помогает. Может кто подскажет свежие идеи что можно сделать?

Comment: не ошибка - уведомление. Если FILEIT - константа, где она инициализированна и как к этому файлу подключена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Константа не определена, поэтому вы получаете уведомление. Если хотите подавить вывод уведомления, оберните код с константой в следующий if:

```
if ( defined( 'FILEIT' ) ) {
    // ваш код...
}
```

Но надо видеть ваш код, что там.